# How to display a category on my homepage?

Tags: cms, phtml, cms-block, setup, home-page

I'm just making my own Magento website and I was wondering if it is possible to display a specific category? I have two categories and I would like to display them separately.

**I'm using this CMS code:**

```
<p>{{widget type="cms/widget_block" template="cms/widget/static_block/default.phtml" block_id="4"}}</p>
<div class="page-title">
<h2>Alle producten</h2>
</div>
<p>{{block type="catalog/navigation" name="catalog.category" template="catalog/category/merken.phtml"}}</p>

<p>{{widget type="cms/widget_block" template="cms/widget/static_block/default.phtml" block_id="4"}}</p>
<div class="page-title">
<h2>Alle producten</h2>
</div>
<p>{{block type="catalog/navigation" name="catalog.category" template="catalog/category/merken.phtml"}}</p>
```

and the merken.phtml contains the following information:

```
<?php
    $class_check=1;
?>
<?php foreach ($this->getStoreCategories() as $_category): ?>

<?php $open = $this->isCategoryActive($_category); ?>
<?php

$cur_category=Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($_category->getId());
$layer = Mage::getSingleton('catalog/layer');
$layer->setCurrentCategory($cur_category);
if ($immagine = $this->getCurrentCategory()->getImageUrl()):
?>
<div class="col-md-2 col-sm-4 col-xs-3 merken-holder <?php if($class_check == 1){echo 'class_first';}?>">
<a href="<?php echo $this->getCategoryUrl($_category); ?>" class="link-img">
<!-- <h1><?php echo $this->htmlEscape($this->getCurrentCategory()->getName()); ?></h1> -->
<img  src="<?php echo $immagine; ?>" alt="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($this->getCurrentCategory()->getName()); ?>" class="merk-image"/>
</a>
</div>



<?php else: ?>
<div class="col-md-2 col-sm-4 col-xs-3 merken-holder <?php if($class_check == 1){echo 'class_first';}?>">
<a href="<?php echo $this->getCategoryUrl($_category); ?>" class="link-img">
<h1><?php echo $this->htmlEscape($this->getCurrentCategory()->getName()); ?></h1>
<!-- <img  src="<?php echo $immagine; ?>" alt="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($this->getCurrentCategory()->getName()); ?>" class="merk-image"/> -->
</a>
</div>
<?php 
endif;
$class_check++;
endforeach; ?>
```

I have 2 of dose codes and also 2 cat ID's

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Do you want to show all categories on home page ?

Answer (score 0):

Replace your code

```
<p>{{block type="catalog/navigation" name="catalog.category" template="catalog/category/merken.phtml"}}</p>
```

To

```
<p>{{block type="catalog/navigation" name="catalog.category" template="catalog/category/merken.phtml" ids="4,3,5"}}</p>
```

I hope it will work for you